# Cloud Firestore : Query nested map of arrays

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore document structure looks like this

**doc1**

```
{
 name: 'Test',
 categories: [
   {
    allNames: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3],
    id: 'abcd'
   },
   {
    allNames: ['name4', 'name5'],
    id: 'xyz'
   },
 ]
```

**doc2**

```
{
 name: 'Test2',
 categories: [
   {
    allNames: ['name7'],
    id: 'abcd3'
   },
   {
    allNames: ['name4', 'name5'],
    id: 'xyz'
   },
 ]
```

I am using the JS SDK and wanted to query all document with a certain category(id or name). So if I query with `categories.id` equal to `xyz` or  `categories.allNames` contains `name1`, both the above documents should be returned.

Are both these queries possible or do I need to remodel my data ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot query arrays that way. If you know the exact object then you could use `array-contains` as shown below:

```
firestore.collection('col').where('categories', 'array-contains', {id: 'abc', allNames: ['name1']})
```

One solution would be to store another array which contains category IDs only like this:

```
{
  name: 'Test1',
  categories: [...],
  categoryIds: ['abcd', 'xyz']
}
```

Now you can use `arrayContains` even if you know the category ID only and not the whole object in categories array. The same method can be used for allNames.

Categories can also be made a sub-collection where each object in categories array would be a document. Then you can use [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries to find category documents with that ID or allNames and find parent document ID using the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference).

Comment: valid. thanks for the explanation :)